# datagridview with populated comboboxs and read from text file

Tags: c#, datagridview, combobox, text-files

I have searched this site and Google for an answer and tried to adapt various answers to my specific situation with no success. I have found a lot of "fill combobox with values from a text file or from DB" and that is not what I need. This is using Visual Studio 2012 in C#.

I have a datagridview that has 4 columns and 17 rows. The top row is just the column names. The first column under the header is #s 1-16 for each row. The rest of the field is comboboxes with specified values all preset that need to stay. This all done by code and not through properties. So if I just go to the datagridview it displays correctly and I can change values and save it. I also need it when the person opens a file and it is displayed, they can click on the combo box and change that value.

I have made it so I can read from a text file in a specific format but the result in the datagridview is 4x17 text boxes with the values. The placement and values are all correct but I need those values to be on the prebuilt comboboxes. The values of the text file will always be one of the values from the prebuilt comboboxes.

This has been a great site to find answers and to use as a starting point for my problems so I'm hoping that I get a little help on this one. I tried to be as specific as possible so I hope you guys can understand.

This is my open dialog and text file read. I'm thinking I need to create my comboboxes or link the creation of them to my prebuilt comboboxes but that is where I'm stumped.

```
if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName);
            string[] columnnames = file.ReadLine().Split(',');
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            foreach (string c in columnnames)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add(c);                    
            }
            string newline;
            while ((newline = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                string[] values = newline.Split(',');
                for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
                {
                    dr[i] = values[i];
                }
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            file.Close();
```

This is my prebuilt combobox code. The values in the comboboxes need to stay. I built it as a constructor because I had it at the load of the form but I changed that and just call upon it when I need to.

```
private void filldata()
    {
        //text column
        dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 1;
        dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "Channel";
        dataGridView1.Columns["Channel"].ReadOnly = true;
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
        dataGridView1[0, 0].Value = "1";
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
        dataGridView1[0, 1].Value = "2";
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
        dataGridView1[0, 2].Value = "3";
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
        dataGridView1[0, 3].Value = "4";
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
        dataGridView1[0, 4].Value = "5";
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
        dataGridView1[0, 5].Value = "6";
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
        dataGridView1[0, 6].Value = "7";
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
        dataGridView1[0, 7].Value = "8";
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
        dataGridView1[0, 8].Value = "9";
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
        dataGridView1[0, 9].Value = "10";
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
        dataGridView1[0, 10].Value = "11";
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
        dataGridView1[0, 11].Value = "12";
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
        dataGridView1[0, 12].Value = "13";
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
        dataGridView1[0, 13].Value = "14";
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
        dataGridView1[0, 14].Value = "15";
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
        dataGridView1[0, 15].Value = "16";

        //combo box
        DataGridViewComboBoxColumn freqRXTX = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
        freqRXTX.HeaderText = "Frequency (MHz)";
        String[] RXTX = { "", "467.0", "471.9", "474.4", "477.0", "479.7" };
        freqRXTX.Items.AddRange(RXTX);
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(freqRXTX);

        DataGridViewComboBoxColumn CTCSSfreq = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
        CTCSSfreq.HeaderText = "CTCSS (Hz)";
        String[] CTCSS = { "none", "67.0", "71.9", "74.4", "77.0", "79.7", "82.5", "85.4", "88.5", "91.5", "94.8", "97.4", "100.0", "103.5", "107.2", "110.9", "114.8", "118.8", "123.0", 
        "127.3", "131.8", "136.5", "141.3", "146.2", "151.4", "118.8", "123.0", "127.3", "131.8", "136.5", "141.3", "146.2", "151.4", "210.7", "218.1", "225.7", "233.6", "241.8", "250.3"};
        CTCSSfreq.Items.AddRange(CTCSS);
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(CTCSSfreq);

        DataGridViewComboBoxColumn DCSfreq = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
        DCSfreq.HeaderText = "DCS (Hz)";
        String[] DCS = { "none", "23", "25", "26", "31", "32", "43", "47", "51", "54", "65", "71", "72", "73", "74", "114", "115", "116", "125", "131", "132", "134", "143", "152", "155", "156", "162", "165",
        "172", "174", "205", "223", "226", "243", "244", "245", "251", "261", "263", "265", "271", "306", "311", "315", "331", "343", "346", "351", "364", 
        "365", "371", "411", "412", "413", "423", "431", "432", "445", "464", "465", "466", "503", "506", "516", "532", "546", "565", "606", "612", "624",
        "627", "631", "632", "654", "662", "664", "703", "712", "723", "731", "732", "734", "743", "754" };
        DCSfreq.Items.AddRange(DCS);
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(DCSfreq);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has a few issues.

The one at hand probably is that you didn't set the `DataPropertyName` of the columns in your `DataGridView`.

You could do that like this, at the and of your first piece of code, i.e. after setting up the table:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; i++)
{
    dataGridView1.Columns[i].DataPropertyName = dt.Columns[i].ColumnName;
}
```

You still need to call the second piece first, as it will set up the `DataGridView`.

In it you could simplifiy the setup like this:

```
//text column
dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 1;
dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "Channel";  // !*!
dataGridView1.Columns["Channel"].ReadOnly = true;
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(16);
for (int i = 1; i <= 16; i++)
{
    dataGridView1[0, i].Value = i + "";
}
..
```

I noticed (!*!) that you set the `Name` property of only one `DataGridView.Column` ('Channel'). This is ok, but a little confusing; try to keep your code consistent, or else your (or soemone else) will start to wonder about it, sometime later..

Note that I didn't do any **checks** for the number of columns in the `DataTable` to be not less than those in the `DataGridView`!

Also note that you are free to associate **any** `DataGridView.Column` with **any** `DataTable.Column` , at least as long as their data types don't clash..
I simply assumed that their order would fit..

Also note that it is worth considering to move the `DataTable` declaration out to class level, so you can access it directly from other pieces of code. It will stay in code anyway as long as it is set as the DGV's `DataSource`; and it can still be accessed by casting the `dataGridView1.DataSource` to `DataTable`, but it would be simpler and clearer, imo. For this you would have to keep the instantiation in the code, just move the declaration!

Note that you usually have to decide whether the datagridview's columns are generated in code or by the data binding source. For the former set `dataGridView1.AutoGeneratecolumns = false;` !

Comment: Thanks for the help. Your answers pointed me in the right direction. I had to add DataPropertyName to my prebuilt datagridview. Then I did a little more research into the DataPropertyName thing. I ran into a the AutoGenerateColumns property and determined from that by leaving that out it was adding columns to my grid. In the beginning I had two strings of code, one would add columns and other would just make a grid of text boxes. So in the end I called my "filldata" before the open dialog and used the AutoGenerateColumns made that false. Thank you for all the help.